# Regular expression for substring with variable length

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a lot of strings like:

```
"1248, 60906068, 4536576, 858687( some text 67, 43, 45)"
```

And I want to check if the string starts from number and there are brackets in string, in same time I want to get all numbers from the begining to the first bracket. So for this example string result should be like:

```
[0] => 1248 , [1] => 60906068, [2] => 4536576, [3] => 858687
```

The point is that in the string after first number at the beginning of the string **could be** **zero additional numbers** or **one number** or even **a lot of numbers**.

I tried something like that:

```
 ^(\d+)(?:,\s?(\d+)?)*\([^\)]+\)$
```

But it takes only first and last number before brackets.

Is it possible to get all these numbers with only one Regular Expression?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex: `(\d+)(?:\([^\)]+\))?`

All numbers will be captured in Group 1.

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/wX0fO2/3).

Result:

```
1248
60906068
4536576
858687
```